# How to get xml attribute value containing multiple colons in a single tag i.e. namespaces?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <feed xml:base="XYZ" xmlns:d="http://schemas/services" xmlns:m="http://schemas/metadata" xmlns="http://www.abc.pqr/Atom">
  <title type="text">Title</title>
  <id>Id</id>
  <updated>2018-02-08</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="titl" href="title" />
  <entry m:etag="W/&quot;25&quot;">
    <id>id1</id>
    <title type="text">title_text</title>
    <updated>2018-02-08</updated>
    <author>
    <name />
    </author>
    <link m:etag="&quot;{acx},25&quot;" rel="edit-media" title="title_value" />
    <link rel="edit" title="title" />
    <link rel="http://az.com/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="title/CreatedBy" />
    <link rel="http://az.com/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy" href="title/ModifiedBy" />
    <link rel="http://az.com/CheckedOutTo" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CheckedOutTo" href="title/CheckedOutTo" />
    <category term="xyz" scheme="xyz" />
    <content type="application/octetstream" src="http://collb.xlsm" />
    <m:properties xmlns:m="http://xyz/metadata" xmlns:d="wsx/dataservices">
       <d:ContentTypeID>contentId</d:ContentTypeID>
       <d:Dept>21</d:Dept>
       <d:Class>0</d:Class>      
       <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2121</d:Id>
    </m:properties>
  </entry>
  <link rel="next" href="http://tyu.com" />
  </feed>
```

I want to read values corresponding to `<d:Id m:type>` and `<entry m:etag>` i.e. output should be `2121` and `25`.

How should I read these.

P.S: I have gone through similar questions asked on stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me.

Part of my code:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
 DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
 Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
 element.getAttributeNodeNS("http://schemas/metadata", "type");
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which of the vast choice of Java APIs you are using. I guess that probably means you're using DOM. I don't know why anyone still uses DOM when there are much better alternatives available, but they do.

Whichever API you are using, you'll find that there's probably a method something like

```
element.getAttributeValue(namespace, localname)
```

To read the `m:type` attribute, you would use

```
element.getAttributeValue("http://schemas/metadata", "type")
```

Comment: I am using DOM parser(DocumentBuilderFactory).I tried doing `element.getAttributeNodeNS("http://schemas/metadata", "type")` but it didn't work. There are two namespaces `d` and `m`. And this function can read for `m`. I tried  `element.getAttributeValue("http://schemas/services", "Dept")` to read the tag value corresponding to `<d:Dept>`, but this is also giving me null.

Comment: Did you make the DOM factory namespace-aware?

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I have added part of my code for your reference.

Comment: Your code is looking for an m:type attribute on the `<feed>` element, which has no such attribute.

Comment: Yes, I know that is incorrect. Help me read value corresponding to `<d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2121</d:Id>` i.e. 2121.